# Non-Sticky Footer CSS Help?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, footer

I want my footer to stick to the bottom of the page, so I used a

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

that brings it to the bottom, however when you re-size your window and it is small, the footer is overlapping everything else on the page.

How do you keep it at the bottom and then if the page is too small, just don't show the footer (not let it overlap other content)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at some "sticky footer css" techniques like:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). This, apart from using javascript, is a very complicated thing to do and in many cases is very implementation specific (will only work on the site it's built on :P).  That site I linked has a way that may or may not work for you.  It didn't work for me when I wanted to do this, but it all depends on the specific circumstances.

Comment: do you have any resources for doing it in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To have the footer shrink or otherwise act differently when the browser is small, you'd need javascript that is triggered by load and resize events (at least) that would check the height of the main page, and when under a specific size would modify the properties of the footer.

It is not possible with CSS alone in any way I can imagine.